# App crash after I call Detoured function I created @ Win7-x64

Tags: c, assembly, 64-bit, windbg, x86-64

I'm new in here and its my first question asked. I hope to get along in here just fine :)
And for my question!:

I wrote a Detouring infrastructure for x64 processor (normal intel x64)

The main interesting functions looks like this:

```
typedef ULONG_PTR (WINAPI *MESSAGEBOX)(HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT);

    DWORD WINAPI DETOUR_MyMessageboxA(MESSAGEBOX OriginalFunction, HWND hWnd, LPCSTR lpText, LPCSTR lpCaption, UINT uType)
    {
        OutputDebugPrintA("Success.");
        return OriginalFunction(hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uType);
    }
```

When I detour MessageBoxA, I wrote the following ASM code:

```
push rdi
push r9

sub rsp, 20
mov rdi, rsp

mov r9, r8
mov r8, rdx
mov rdx, ecx
mov ecx, [ORIGINAL_ADDRESS]

call DETOUR_MyMessageboxA

add rsp, 20

pop r9
pop rdi
ret
```

The idea is to basically "Shift right" the arguments and add another argument (My original function address) to the detour. 
I hope I got it right, the calling convention is as the following:

First Arg: **RCX**

Second Arg: **RDX**

Third Arg: **R8**

Fourth Arg: **R9**

Anything more in rsp (under the "Shadow space" thingy)

Just making sure in on the same page with everyone.. the stack should look like this before calling a function:

```
    GARBAGE.....
RSP RetAddress
    8BYTE-GARBAGE - [Shadow space]
    8BYTE-GARBAGE - [Shadow space]
    8BYTE-GARBAGE - [Shadow space]
    8BYTE-GARBAGE - [Shadow space]
    Arg5
    Arg6
    ...
```

Now after I begin me detour and my Assembly code is called instead of the original function I get an exception:

```
0:000> g
(624.17b4): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
ntdll!RtlCaptureContext+0x86:
00000000`76d508c5 0fae8100010000  fxsave  [rcx+100h]    ds:00000000`0026ead8=50
0:000> k
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`0026e998 00000000`76d195c8 ntdll!RtlCaptureContext+0x86
00000000`0026e9a8 000007fe`fccc940d ntdll!RtlRaiseException+0x48
00000000`0026efe8 000007fe`fccdaa0d KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x39
00000000`0026f0b8 000007fe`f6ec2c7a KERNELBASE!OutputDebugStringA+0x6d
00000000`0026f388 00000000`0014002f Detour_RekSai!DETOUR_MyMessageboxA+0x3a [c:\projects\test.c @ 14]
00000000`0026f3b8 00000000`00130000 0x14002f
00000000`0026f3c0 00000000`00000000 0x130000
0:000> !vprot 00000000`0026ead8
BaseAddress:       000000000026e000
AllocationBase:    00000000001f0000
AllocationProtect: 00000004  PAGE_READWRITE
RegionSize:        0000000000002000
State:             00001000  MEM_COMMIT
Protect:           00000004  PAGE_READWRITE
Type:              00020000  MEM_PRIVATE
0:000> db rcx+100 L20
00000000`0026ead8  50 f0 26 00 00 00 00 00-58 f9 26 00 00 00 00 00  P.&.....X.&.....
00000000`0026eae8  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-e9 c9 ec f6 fe 07 00 00  ................
0:000> !gle
LastErrorValue: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000008 (3221225480) - An invalid HANDLE was specified.
LastStatusValue: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.
```

Now I have no idea what is causing this..
I think I got all the variables and stuck correctly.. didn't I?
I have no clue what this memory location is or why it happens.

Thanks for any help..

**EDIT**:
If I remove the "OutputDebugPrint" in my function:

```
DWORD WINAPI DETOUR_MyMessageboxA(MESSAGEBOX OriginalFunction, HWND hWnd, LPCSTR lpText, LPCSTR lpCaption, UINT uType)
{
    return OriginalFunction(hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uType);
}
```

I still get an exception (A different one, but Something tells me they are both caused because of the same thing).

```
0:000> g
(1e3c.298c): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
LPK!LpkCharsetDraw+0x78:
000007fe`fe811775 440f29842450010000 movaps xmmword ptr [rsp+150h],xmm8 ss:00000000`0026ebf8=000007fefe91a8e40000000002051320
0:000> k
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`0026eaa8 000007fe`fe8114cc LPK!LpkCharsetDraw+0x78
00000000`0026ec68 00000000`76af85c5 LPK!LpkDrawTextEx+0x68
00000000`0026ecd8 00000000`76af87fc USER32!DT_DrawStr+0xa6
00000000`0026ed78 00000000`76af8216 USER32!DT_GetLineBreak+0x241
00000000`0026ee28 00000000`76b51e07 USER32!DrawTextExWorker+0x3f8
00000000`0026ef38 00000000`76b523e9 USER32!MB_CalcDialogSize+0x187
00000000`0026efd8 00000000`76b51c15 USER32!SoftModalMessageBox+0x47d
00000000`0026f108 00000000`76b5146b USER32!MessageBoxWorker+0x31d
00000000`0026f2c8 00000000`76b51362 USER32!MessageBoxTimeoutW+0xb3
00000000`0026f398 000007fe`ecfe2c85 USER32!MessageBoxW+0x4e
00000000`0026f3d8 00000000`0015002f Detour_RekSai!DETOUR_MyMessageboxA+0x45 [c:\users\ariel\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\detour_reksai\detour_reksai\test.c @ 19]
00000000`0026f408 00000000`00140000 0x15002f
00000000`0026f410 00000000`00000000 0x140000
0:000> !vprot [rsp+150h]
BaseAddress:       000000000026e000
AllocationBase:    00000000001f0000
AllocationProtect: 00000004  PAGE_READWRITE
RegionSize:        0000000000002000
State:             00001000  MEM_COMMIT
Protect:           00000004  PAGE_READWRITE
Type:              00020000  MEM_PRIVATE
0:000> db [rsp+150h] L20
00000000`0026ebf8  20 13 05 02 00 00 00 00-e4 a8 91 fe fe 07 00 00   ...............
00000000`0026ec08  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0:000> !gle
LastErrorValue: (Win32) 0 (0) - The operation completed successfully.
LastStatusValue: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have missed this line: `This exception may be expected and handled.`
The exception as reported is coming from the `OutputDebugPrintA`, and I doubt that has much to do with your detouring logic. Make sure this is a real unhandled exception.

PS: Not sure what you wanted to do with `mov edi, esp`.

---

As per the comments, it seems your problem is `rsp` misalignment. You should maintain 16 byte alignment. In this case, you are pushing 2 items (worth 16 bytes) and then adjusting by 32, and finally you have a `call` which places 8 bytes of return address on the stack. All in all, you have 8 byte misalignment. Since in this code you don't need `rdi`, you can simply omit the `push`/`pop` for that and thereby fix the misalignment. Also, using `mov` makes the situation clearer:

```
sub rsp, 28h

mov [rsp+20h], r9
mov r9, r8
mov r8, rdx
mov rdx, rcx
mov ecx, [ORIGINAL_ADDRESS]

call DETOUR_MyMessageboxA

add rsp, 28h
ret
```

---

> How I should implement a lets say 5 variable function detour?

```
mov rax, [rsp+28h] ; 5th arg
sub rsp, 38h       ; space for 6 args + alignment

mov [rsp+28h], rax
mov [rsp+20h], r9
mov r9, r8
mov r8, rdx
mov rdx, rcx
mov ecx, [ORIGINAL_ADDRESS]

call DETOUR

add rsp, 38h
ret
```

Comment: Whenever there is an exception (any kind of exception) before it is handled it is first shown to me at the debugger..

I have more OutputDebugPrintA s in the code which do not generate this error

The same error occurs when there is just the call to the original function. even without the OutputDebugPrint

Also sorry about that Mov expression it was a typo


what i meant to write was "mov rdi, rsp" I saw this going on a lot on many functions before calling them so i just tried it aswell if it might fix the problem.. it didnt

Comment: Yes, they are all shown to you first. Doesn't mean they won't be handled by the code. Make sure it is really a fatal exception if you continue. Also, remove the `OutputDebugPrint` and post updated exception stack trace, along with the relevant instruction from your code if applicable.

Comment: I edited and inserted the new stack trace (along with the old one)


When i write 'g' \ 't' again in windbg its just stuck at the same instruction. if i run it without a debugger it would just stop the execution and wouldnt run the expected functions.

Comment: Ah of course. You have a simple mistake: `sub rsp, 20`. The `20` should be in hex, or 32 decimal (same for the `add` of course). You are misaligning the stack pointer.

Comment: This is not it..
The instruction it self looks like this in windbg:

"**00000000`00140004 4883ec20        sub     rsp,20h**"

its hexadecimal

Comment: In that case try using `28h` (`40`) because the `call` also places 8 bytes on the stack and you might be required to keep `rsp` 16 byte aligned. In the second exception trace you can see that `rsp+150h` is `26ebf8h` which is misaligned and `movaps` doesn't like that.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions \ ideas of how i should implement a lets say 5 variable function detour without messing up the stuck? (considering im also pushing the Original function address in ecx)

Comment: yeah well i need something generic.. not exclusively 5 args

with 6?
or 7?

Is there a way to do it generically?

Comment: You need to know how many arguments you have to copy. If you don't, a generic hack could be to add 2 arguments, not 1, so you don't mess up the alignment, and move the return address.